# ActionBarActivity doesn´t shows my AppIcon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I´m trying to add in my ActionBar my app icon, but I was reading on Google Developers and I can get the solution. I´m doing this on my ActivityMain:

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

But it doesn´t work.

This is my first day with Android and I just want make an ActionBar with the main icon on the left and an icon search.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With API21 you should use the new Toolbar class.

Put the `Toolbar` in your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Then in your code (`onCreate` in your Activity for example):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_myNavigationIcon);
```

You can find more info in the [official post](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing the logo, which is by default the same as the launcher icon.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following steps to implement `ActionBar` :

1 - Extend `ActionBarActivity` like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Notice to import this :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

2 - Add lines below into `onCreate` :

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

3- Create your `xml` menu under `res/menu/your_menu.xml` 
somthing like this :

**your_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

4- Inflate the menu to the action bar, and handle the action bar item clicks :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is   present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.your_menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope this help you!!!